# c# globalizaion-localizacion aplicacion winform sin salir

Tags: c#, localización

Estoy usando ResX Resource Manager.
Tengo un combobox para elegir el Idioma de la aplicacion winform.
Si cambio de idioma (queda grabada la nueva seleccion), salgo y vuelvo a entrar, se rellena el formulario sin necesidad de recorrer los controles, excepto aquellos mas complejos como el combobox.

```
CultureInfo r;
r = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
r.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
r.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = r;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = r;
```

Este codigo lo ejecuto dentro de un switch para cada idioma.

Cuando cambio de idioma lo vuelvo a ejecutar pero no cambia el contenido del formulario.
Tambien e tratado volviendo a crear el formulario.

Revise la web y recomiendan recorrer los controles con un foreach y rellenarlos, pero eso nunca lo hago e igual funciona (tampoco he conseguido que ese metodo funcione, pues busca las traducciones en otro archivo .resX).

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

        cargoIdioma();
        
        comienzo c = new comienzo();
        _ = c.Comienzo();
        
        Application.Exit();
    }


class comienzo : ApplicationContext
    {
        public async Task Comienzo()
        {               
            ITareasPrevias tp = new TareasPrevias();

            // Personalizar
            datosPublicos.awNomPrograma = "Remate";

            using (FormTareasPrevias ftp = new FormTareasPrevias(datosPublicos.awNomPrograma
                , new AControlArchivo(Application.StartupPath, "", ""), tp))
            {
                ftp.Text = "Programa " + datosPublicos.awNomPrograma + " - Tareas Previas";                 
                ftp.ShowDialog();
            }
            FormInicio fi;

            if (tp.lwEstado)
            {                   
                do
                {
                    fi = new FormInicio();
                    fi.Text = "Programa " + await configBase.awNomPrograma() + " - Inicio";
                    fi.InsertarCaratula(Properties.Resources.RemateLogo);
                    fi.conEmpresa = false;
                    FormMPrincipal fmp = new FormMPrincipal();
                    if (await configBase.awPathOrigenDBDatos() == Application.StartupPath)
                    {
                        fmp.Text = "Programa " + datosPublicos.awNomPrograma + " - Menú Principal - " + "--- SERVIDOR ---";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fmp.Text = "Programa " + datosPublicos.awNomPrograma + " - Menú Principal - " + "--- CLIENTE  ---";
                    }
                    fmp.awAyudaMenuPrincipal = Ayudas.FormMPrincipal().ToString();


                    await fi.InicializoSkin();
                    fi.ShowDialog();
                    if (fi.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                    {                           
                        fmp.cargoUsuario(await configBase.awNomUsuario());
                        fmp.cargoRelease(await configBase.nwNroVersion(), await configBase.nwRelease());                
                        fmp.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else if (fi.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    {
                        await fi.GraboSaliBien();
                    }
                 } while ((fi.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) || (fi.DialogResult == DialogResult.Retry) || (fi.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes));
                ExitThread();
            }
        }
    }

public static void cargoIdioma()
    {
        CultureInfo cultureInfo;
        if (FileUtility.ExisteArchivo(Application.StartupPath, "DBDatos.sqlite"))
        {
            if (DataSqlite.existeTabla(new AControlArchivo(Application.StartupPath, "DBDatos", "config")).Result)
            {
                datosPublicos.awCarpetaActual = Application.StartupPath;
                string awIdioma = configBase.awIdioma().Result;
                switch (awIdioma)
                {
                    #region Español
                    case "ES":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                         cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    #region Ingles
                    case "EN":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    #region Aleman
                    case "DE":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    #region Frances
                    case "FR":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    #region Portugues
                    case "PT":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    #region Italiano
                    case "IT":
                        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                        break;
                    #endregion
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                
                                    cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
                cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
                cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Con _salgo y vuelvo a entrar_  te refieres a cerrar la aplicacion o el formulario?

Comment: me refiero a cerrar la aplicacion, el formulario lo cierro y lo vuelvo a abrir y nada